# Type check JavaScript stored as string?

Tags: typescript

I have some JavaScript modules stored as strings, they are evaluated by [Quick.js](https://bellard.org/quickjs/).

Heres an example:

```
const logic = `
  export function foobar() { return true; }
`;
```

I would like a way to type check the code stored in the `logic` constant using TypeScript but I can't find anything, the only solutions I found revolve around running Node.js scripts that copy the code in a new file and then run TS on them.

I would like a solution that works automatically in my IDE instead.

Comment: If you want type checking (+ all the other IDE features, e.g. syntax highlighting), wouldn't it make more sense to build the function in typescript to begin with and then generate these string representations as part of the build process?

Comment: @DBS that could be a solution but I hoped there would be a way that didn't require a build step. I read that people created CSS type checkers using TypeScript template literals capabilities so I thought this would be possible too.

Comment: To be clear, you are looking for something written in Typescript, which can typecheck Typescript code in strings using template literal types? This would essentially require translating the Typescript checker itself into Typescript types.

Comment: @FezVrasta the grammar of CSS is *significantly* less complicated than Javascript's.

Comment: @kaya3 Typeception.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a custom ESLint plugin that will type check any string literal or template literal if prefixed by `/*javascript*/`, for example:

```js
export const foo = /*javascript*/ `
/**
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
export function bar() { return 'string'; }
`;
```

This plays nicely with the `es6-string-javascript` (`zjcompt.es6-string-javascript`) VS Code extension, that'll take care to syntax highlight the JavaScript code.

The plugin is the following, you can use it with the `eslint-local-rules` ESLint plugin:

```js
const { ESLintUtils } = require('@typescript-eslint/utils');
const ts = require('typescript');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');

const checkJsInStringRule = ESLintUtils.RuleCreator((name) => name)({
  meta: {
    type: 'problem',
    docs: {
      description: 'Check JavaScript code stored in strings and template literals',
      category: 'Possible Errors',
      recommended: false,
    },
    schema: [],
    messages: {
      jsInStringError: 'Error in JavaScript code inside string or template literal: {{error}}',
    },
  },
  defaultOptions: [],
  create(context) {
    function hasJavascriptComment(node) {
      const sourceCode = context.getSourceCode();
      const commentsBefore = sourceCode.getCommentsBefore(node);

      return (
        commentsBefore.length > 0 &&
        commentsBefore.some((comment) => comment.value.trim() === 'javascript')
      );
    }

    function checkCode(code, node) {
      const tempDir = fs.mkdtempSync(path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'eslint-'));
      const tempFile = path.join(tempDir, 'temp.js');

      fs.writeFileSync(tempFile, code);

      const program = ts.createProgram([tempFile], {
        allowJs: true,
        checkJs: true,
        noEmit: true,
      });
      const sourceFile = program.getSourceFile(tempFile);
      const diagnostics = ts.getPreEmitDiagnostics(program, sourceFile);

      fs.rmSync(tempDir, { recursive: true });

      if (diagnostics) {
        diagnostics.forEach((diagnostic) => {
          const message = ts.flattenDiagnosticMessageText(diagnostic.messageText, '\n');
          context.report({
            node,
            messageId: 'jsInStringError',
            data: {
              error: message,
            },
          });
        });
      }
    }

    return {
      Literal(node) {
        if (typeof node.value !== 'string') {
          return;
        }

        if (!hasJavascriptComment(node)) {
          return;
        }

        const code = node.value.trim();
        checkCode(code, node);
      },
      TemplateLiteral(node) {
        if (!hasJavascriptComment(node)) {
          return;
        }

        const code = node.quasis.map((quasi) => quasi.value.raw).join('');
        checkCode(code, node);
      },
    };
  },
});

module.exports = {
  'check-js-in-string': checkJsInStringRule,
};
```

This will make TypeScript type check the code and report any error through ESLint.